Cannot run Blazor projects in Rider 2024.X
I get the following error whenever I try to run a Blazor project:

It seems somehow its related to Chrome or a Chrome profile not being available for Rider. The folder chrome-user-data indeed doesn't exist on disk. Uninstalling and re-installing Rider doesn't help. I've wiped the .idea folder and cleared all caches in Rider too.
Here is a thread on Jetbrains but nothing there doesn't help me solve the problem.
Using MacOS 15.1 and Jetbrains Rider JetBrains Rider 2024.3 (Build #RD-243.21565.191, built on November 13, 2024)
Anyone has a similar error and know how to solve it? It's very frustrating. I keep having to use Rider 2023 because there it all works.

Would you mind trying the following steps to see if that helps?

Go to Settings | Tools | Web Browsers and Preview;
Select Chrome browser and press Pen icon (edit):

Tick "Use custom user data directory" and select a folder outside of your home directory.
Press OK -> Save, then try to launch your project.

If that doesn't help, please report an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Thanks for your input! I am not fully sure when or why my Rider started to behave differently, but I do realize I forgot to mention that I am not using Chrome but instead the Brave browser which runs on Chromium. When I installed Chrome it worked, but also when I pointed to the actual Brave file it worked. (still not sure why it stopped work in the first case, but anyway now it's good enough!)
